# Autocomplete widget (jQuery UI) - why the line breaks?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm having some issues with the autocomplete widget. When you choose an option, the item value is prefixed with a line break and some whitespace. Here's how the result shows up:

```
Object { label="\n                     bedroom", value="\n                    bedroom"}
```

I donno why that is happening, maybe it's the way I'm setting up the array to get the values from? Here's my code:

```
$("#step2").show(0, function() {
                /*tags auto-complete*/        
                var tags = $('span', $('#liTags')).text();
                var availableTags = tags.split(' ;');
                $(".liTagInput").autocomplete({ 
                    minLength: 2,
                    source: availableTags,
                    select: function(event, ui) {
                        var value = ui.item;
                        console.log(value);
                        console.log(jQuery.inArray(value, availableTags));
                        if(jQuery.inArray(value, availableTags) >= 0) 
                            $(this).val('');
                    } 
                });

            });
```

In case you are wondering what I'm trying to do here (which I haven't tested yet because of the line breaks), I'm getting the tags from a span element on the HTML side, then splitting those into an array (`availableTags`).

Then what I want to happen is that once a user types something into the text box, if it is not something he/she chose from the auto-complete menu, then the value of the text field should be cleared out (I might also show them a warning telling them to choose from the menu but let's leave that for now).

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't use

```
string.replace(/\s/g, "");
```

to remove whitespaces using [**replace()**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) method.

And to remove all line breaks use

```
string.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
```

---

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/tjfmp/

Comment: @ArtWorkAD: I was thinking of doing something similar but I would still want to know where the line breaks are coming from. Moreover, how do I intercept the value of the chosen auto-complete menu option to remove the whitespace?

Comment: it seems your "avaiable tags" have these line breaks. Try do log available tags to determine the reason for the line breaks. Why do you have the whitespace at split(" ;") ?

Comment: @ArtWorkAD: That is because the tags - in the span element - are separated by a space and a semi-column. I'll remove the space and test it.

Comment: @ArtWorkAD: that did not solve the problem... Could you please edit your answer to show me what value I should intercept to remove the whitespaces? Thank you.

Comment: @ArtWorkAD: After messing around with the auto-complete events and using your example I got it working. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

[`string.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) is made for this very purpose.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10668604)

Comment: @SergeyDenisov - but it's not just a link.